# PCA or Drop high correlated variables for clustering

Tags: r, pca, distance, hierarchical-clustering, mixed-type-data

I am performing clustering on mixed data type. I have few features which are high correlated. We generally use PCA before clustering and reduce the feature space, as its a mixed data I have used FAMD to reduce the feature space. I have scaled the principle components and then When I do clustering, My clustering is very poor.

I also tried manually removing the features which are highly correlated and applied gower distance and then did clustering. Then I saw a good clustering performance. I am using `Hclust()` and `pam()` in R for both the methods. Why is my clustering perfomance not getting better when I use FAMD and why is it better when I remove high correlated variables manually? Can someone please clarify this.

Hi All, Sure. @christian Hennig, I am measuring my clustering performance by Average silhouette width, my aim of clustering is to cluster 21 features in which 20 are numerical and 1 is nominal to 3 clusters where each cluster suggests the health of the babies. After applying FAMD, I have tested with 6 components for which eigen value is more than 1 and also tested by taking 15 components which explain 85% of the variance. I removed 4 variables manually when I tried removing them. I decided these numbers based on the correlation matrix where I saw that these 4 variables exhibit high correlation with other 4 variables. @kjetil b halvorsen Hclust is Hirerachial Clustering, PAM, Means partitioning around the mediods, PCA is a principle component analysis, and FAMD is a factor analysis of a mixed data

Comment: How do you measure "clustering performance"? What is your aim of clustering? How many features do you have, how many factors/PCs do you use, how many variables do you remove manually? How do you decide these numbers?

Comment: This has been addressed in other topics.  Generally speaking, dropping variables works less well than combining variables.

Comment: Can you please explain your abbrevs?

Comment: Hi All, I have answered above questions in my main post.

Comment: I'd be interested to see what you mean by "highly correlated." My best guess is that the variables you are removing are substantively changing the makeup of the dataset as a whole. So, while, say, V1 & V2 are highly correlated with each other, they may have very different relationships with other variables in the data set.

Comment: Average Silhouette Width values cannot easily be compared between clusterings based on different variables, as changing the involved variables also changes the distance measure on which the ASW is based. So the ASW getting larger or smaller when using different variable selection methods doesn't allow to say that "clustering performance" is better or worse in any absolute sense. You should not rely on ASW to decide what is a better or worse choice of variables for your clustering.